# jstree initially selected menu causes infinity loop;

Tags: jstree

I'm using jstree_pre1.0_fix_1. And I want to have the preselected menu.

javascript is following,

```
$("#Menu").jstree({ 
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "ui"],
    "ui" :{ "initially_select" : ["#MENUITEM_012"] },
    "themes" : {
        "theme" : "custom",
        "dots" : false,
        "icons" : false,
    },
}).
bind("select_node.jstree", function(e,data) {
    window.location.href = data.rslt.obj.children("a").attr("href");
});
```

When jstree is loaded, it selects a node(#MENUITEM_012), then window.location.href is changed, then jstree loaded and selects a node again.

How can I escape this situation.

Comment: what is the point of this line?  window.location.href = data.rslt.obj.children("a").attr("href");

Comment: Each node has 'a' tag. For example, `<li id="MENUITEM_012"><a href="/onlinehelp/help/Page.action?pageid=012">TITLE012</a></li>`. So when the node is selected, new page is loaded.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution. The problem is caused by the library trying to select the node( i.e. to make it appear selected after the navigated page is loaded). And handler had been set when a node is visited to navigate the page to another page.

The solution is to make sure that the node is selected with a mouse click.

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function(e,data) {
    var evt =  window.event || event;
    var button = evt.which || evt.button;
    if( button != 1 || ( typeof button == "undefined")) return true;

    window.location.href = data.rslt.obj.children("a").attr("href");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer myself;

remove

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function(e,data) {
    window.location.href = data.rslt.obj.children("a").attr("href");
})
```

add

```
$(".jstree li a").live("click", function(e) {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: Did you find a better solution than this?